# Why is our moderation queue order different from the other sites I have access to?

Tags: feature-request, bug

Below are the review queues for ELU, ELL, and 3DP:

[image: ELU] [image: ELL] [image: 3DP]

Is there some reason that the order here is not the same across sites?

Comment: honestly? No idea... Bug?

Comment: Based on my testing on SO, Android.SE, and Anime.SE... the cause of the difference is that ELU, ELL (SO, Android.SE and the rest) have their own site-design, and 3DP (Anime.SE, along with many other sites) are still using common (aka. "beta") site design. But still, the underlying question is valid: why is the order different? ._.?

Comment: Davo, it might be a good idea to mark Glorfindel's answer as the accepted one... :-)

Comment: Oops, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order is different because this is a beta site. They're shown in the order of reputation required to access them (and then alphabetical).

So First Posts and Late Answers are always at the bottom (requiring 500 reputation on graduated sites and 350 on beta sites like 3D Printing). On beta sites, Close Votes and Reopen Votes are next (at 500 reputation), followed by Low Quality Posts and Suggested Edits (1000 reputation) at the top. On graduated sites, it's the other way around: Low Quality Posts and Suggested Edits at 2000 reputation, and Close Votes and Reopen Votes at 3000 reputation.

Or, as [Shog9 put it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346651/4751173):

> They're ordered *first* by the minimum reputation needed to access the queue, and *then* alphabetically by the name of the queue.
>
> The purpose of this ordering is to keep the list as consistent as possible *until your privilege-level changes* - the hope is that folks use this as their primary means of accessing the queues, and as such we're not forcing reviewers to override their muscle-memory every time they go to access a specific queue - a worthy design goal for a menu that appears on just about every page of the site.